# findOne result return nulls for Collection in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

when I run this code - it output null

```
Card.findOne({userId : model.userId} , function (err, cardData) {
        console.log(err); //output null
        console.log(cardData); //output null
    });
```

the expected to output null if card exist and cardData

> console.log(err); //output null
>
> console.log(cardData); //output cardData {json formatted}

sample document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b32712d90bd3e000454ce92"),
    "reactions" : {
        "likes" : [],
        "disLikes" : [],
        "comments" : []
    },
    "code" : "1qf28",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2018-06-26T17:00:29.542Z"),
    "reports" : [],
    "userId" : "5b2bee8c47ca27344f5425cf",
    "name" : "Ahmed Mohsen",
    "phone" : "01233556",
    "gender" : "male",
    "public" : true,
    "position" : "Developer ",
    "subtitle" : "Free costa",
    "img" : "https://i.imgur.com/2qLGIWa.jpg",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**UPDATE**

the userId is undefined

however I send it - through this code

```
axios.get(settings.default.baseUrl + '/api/cards/check_user_card' , {userId : userId})
```

Comment: Can you show the sample document?

Comment: @Neodan , I updated the question

Comment: Can you check to see what `model.userId` value is ?

Comment: Oh -> undefined

Comment: however I send it : axios.get(settings.default.baseUrl + '/api/cards/check_user_card' , {userId : userId})

Comment: You should check the request you get in server to see what value is. Maybe you are getting wrong field.

Comment: can u update your router

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
Card.findOne({userId : new ObjectId(model.userId)} , function (err, cardData) {
    console.log(err); //output null
    console.log(cardData); //output null
});
```